# I can’t show the version of an NPM package (nodemon --version), what to do?

Tags: npm, terminal, nodemon, hyperterminal

I tried to run codes in my hyper-terminal (deleted nodemon and then reinstalled it) but at the end I still can NOT get the version of my nodemon, it says:
"C:\Users\azadk\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found"

Here’s what I tried to do:

[image]

I also tried to set the path of Environment variables to "C:\Program Files\nodejs" but still I can’t get the version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to some sort of VPN or your corporate internet, try to connect to another network and run the call again.

Answer (score 0):

I entered these commands and the problem was resolved:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```